# Is there thread switching when moving from Default dispatcher to IO dispatcher using withContext?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines

According to the document of `Dispatchers.IO`

```
This dispatcher shares threads with the [Default][Dispatchers.Default] dispatcher, so using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` when already running on the [Default][Dispatchers.Default] dispatcher does not lead to an actual switching to another thread - typically execution continues in the same thread. As a result of thread sharing, more than 64 (default parallelism) threads can be created (but not used) during operations over IO dispatcher.
```

My test code is:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    repeat(4) {
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            println("Start $it in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                println("Continue $it in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                delay(10)
                println("Resume $it in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code explain: Creating 4 coroutine running with `Default` dispatcher, switching to `IO` dispatcher, then delay the coroutine for 10ms and resume.

I would expect that every coroutine will `start` and `continue` in the same thread as mentioned in the above doc, then might resume in another thread. But when I run the code, the output shows me a different result.

```
Start 0 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Start 1 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Start 2 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
Start 3 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
Continue 0 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
Continue 1 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Continue 2 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Continue 3 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Resume 0 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Resume 1 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Resume 2 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-11
Resume 3 in DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
```

As you can see, coroutine 0 starts in thread 1 and continue in thread 6 after `withContext`. The same for other coroutines.

Could anybody explain why?